# How to find the underlying type in a C# generic class to be used in a generic function?

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have a C# type :

```
class MyType<T>
{
   T Value { get; set; }
   // etc.
}
```

And some specialized types :

```
class MyTypeString : MyType<string>
{
   // etc.
}


class MyTypeDate : MyType<Date>
{
   // etc.
}
```

I want to write a generic function where I will be able to manipulate (and even create) objects of type `MyTypeString` or `MyTypeDate`, and at the same time return/modify the underlying type value (`string` or `Date`).

My current solution is something like:

```
T_Underlying Foo<T, T_Underlying>(ref T p_variable, T_Underlying p_value)
        where T : MyType<T_Underlying>, new()
{
    if(p_variable == null)
    {
        p_variable = new T() ;
    }

    p_variable.Value = p_value ;

    return p_value ;
}
```

But this solution is too much verbose for my taste, as to call the method, I need to provide all types, both the principal and the underlying type :

```
MyTypeString myTypeString = null ;
string value ;

value = Foo<MyTypeString, string>(ref myTypeString, "Hello World") ;
```

Is there a way in C# to make the following line possible ?

```
value = Foo<MyTypeString>(ref myTypeString, "Hello World") ;
```

Or even :

```
value = Foo(ref myTypeString, "Hello World") ;
```

???

*P.S.: `MyTypeString` is a generic on `string`, so I have a hunch `MyTypeString` should be able to give me its underlying type, but while I know how to do it in C++, I don't know how to do it in C#, or even if it is possible.*

*P.P.S.: The example is dumb, I know, but in the real code have both a Setter and a Getter, thus explaining the "set and get" look and feel of Foo.*

### Edit

As written above, I mixed both my Getter/Setter to ask this question, without realizing the problem was with the Getter :

```
T_Underlying Get<T, T_Underlying>(ref T p_variable)
        where T : MyType<T_Underlying>, new()
{
    if(p_attributeMember == null)
    {
        return default(T_Underlying) ;
    }

    return p_attributeMember.Value ;
}
```

The error (On Monodevelop for Ubuntu 10.10, i.e. C# 3.5) was :

> Error CS0411: The type arguments for method `MyType.Get(ref T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly (CS0411)

But I guess [Magnus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847675/how-to-find-the-underlying-type-in-a-c-generic-class-to-be-used-in-a-generic-fun/5847921#5847921) could help me there, or I would change the prototype of the Getter to put the returned value as second `out` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

oxilumin is right, your current solution already works as you want.
But to answer your question on how to get the underlying generic type:

```
var type = p_variable.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Comment: + for the answear. Such a shame I can't give another for the Duke logo.

Answer (score 6):

C# has [Type inference in generics method](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/10/c-type-inference-in-generic-methods.html) so you can write just

```
value = Foo(ref myTypeString, "hello world");
```

using your current solution.

Comment: +1.You're right. In my test, I have both a Getter and a Setter, and the Foo function above has a similar prototype to the Setter, which works. The Getter, though, is different. I'll update my question.

Comment: If he answered your question, then you should mark it as answered.  Then you should probably open up a new question because this question could start becoming very localized.

Comment: If you do not change p_variable in getter - use MyType<TUnderlying> instead of ref T.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `typeof` keyword to get the type?